# When should I pause between shell commands in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I'm running a script of multiple commands using Linux and I want to know if I should use the **sleep/pause** script or not?

What's the **disadvantage** of not using sleep/pause? And will it affect my script? 
**My script** for example will be looking like this :

```
#!/bin/bash   
rm -rf /var/www/testdir/*  
echo "Example1 deleted."  
cp -r /var/www/testdirOrig/* /var/www/testdir/  
echo "Example1 copied original files."
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you considering using pause? Are you running stuff in parallel?

Comment: There's no reason AFAIK to pause in that script - you are just deleting some stuff and copying some stuff afterwards. It will work fine, it's not Windows.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you, so the commands will not run in parallel, right?

Comment: No, each command will run to completion before running the next.

Comment: Okay great. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 2):

The commands should be sequenced one after another.
Pausing/sleeping is not something you should normally do, except perhaps when busy-waiting for some file to appear (though there are better ways for that too)

Comment: Hey @PaulStelian , so what I'm doing is trying to copy a 1 GB of file and deleting it, and I want to know if I should use Pausing/Sleeping between the commands, i added the script in my question.

Comment: The copying is a blocking command so, by the time the command finishes, the file is done copying.